# How to show a loading image (using a4j)?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

The following code in my .xhtml works fine:

```
<h:commandButton id="btnConsultar" 
                 action="#cadastrarProponenteBean.consultarCnpj}" 
                 value="#{messages.tx_consultar}"
                 styleClass="btnAcao" />
```

But, when I add `a4j:support`:

```
<h:commandButton id="btnConsultar"
                 action="#{cadastrarProponenteBean.consultarCnpj}" 
                 value="#{messages.tx_consultar}"
                 styleClass="btnAcao">

    <a4j:support event="onclick" />
</h:commandButton>
```

the application breaks, I get strange errors, and my validation `messages('getFacesContext().addMessage')` are not shown.

Since I'm using `a4j:support` just to show a loading gif when user clicks, any advice on how to fix this problem?

I'm using JSF and RichFaces.

PS: already tried `a4j:commandButton` instead of `h:commandButton` but same problems...

Comment: *"I get strange errors"* Good errors already represent answers in its entirety. Being unable to interpret them doesn't mean that you should ignore them and skip them from the question. Instead, copypaste them unmodified in the question. We are able to translate errors into layman's terms so you finally undestand them and can fix the cause. Of course, you can also copypaste errors in a search engine. More than often they are already explained elsewhere. Please edit your question to include the errors.

Comment: God point, what I called strange errors:  
**Caused by: org.jboss.seam.core.LockTimeoutException: could not acquire lock on @Synchronized component: cadastrarProponenteBean**

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<a4j:status>` similar to:

```
    <a4j:status id="ajaxstatus" rendered="true">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:graphicImage value="/images/loading.gif" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="stop">
        </f:facet>
    </a4j:status>
```

I have it in template. Loading image is displayed during any long action.

Comment: I've tried your solution and got the following error:  

`        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: duplicate Id for a component _viewRoot:status
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.TreeStructureNode.apply(TreeStructureNode.java:68)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.TreeStructureNode.apply(TreeStructureNode.java:92)`

Comment: `duplicate Id` clearly identified that problem is with id. It looks like you already have UI component with id _ajaxstatus_ on the page. Check it and rename some if needed or fix content of `a4j:status` if it exists. In general it is not related to your problem with loading image.

Comment: Solved with `forcedId="true"`, still doesn't work. What am I missing?
`     <h:commandButton id="btnConsultar"
      action="#{cadastrarProponenteBean.consultarCnpj}"
      value="#{messages.tx_consultar}" styleClass="btnAcao" >
         <a4j:status id="ajaxstatus" rendered="true" forceId="true">
             <f:facet name="start">
                 <h:panelGroup>
                     <h:graphicImage value="/img/aguarde.gif" />
                 </h:panelGroup>
             </f:facet>
             <f:facet name="stop">
             </f:facet>
         </a4j:status>      
     </h:commandButton>`

Comment: It should not be part of commandButton. It usually sitting in view (I have it in template for all pages in application as part of title in one app or as independent line between menu and page content in second app)